# Split dictionary based on a value

Tags: python

**Note:Update the question so it focuses on one problem only*.

*The question focus on one problem only: Divide the dictionary in two. Nothing else**

I would like to split a dictionary in two.

With these conditions:

1. **The dictionary keys are not in order**

For example I have

```
dd={517.1: 'h', 182.8:'o', 306.5:'l', 378.2:'a'}
```

and I have a dividing key `378.2`

I would like to get:

```
d1= { 182.8:'o', 306.5:'l'}
d2= { 517.1: 'h'}
```

As you can see the dictionary got divided in two according to the key and the dividing key was not included in the results

Comment: I don't see the logic to this...

Comment: how ar they divided logically, the key was at the end

Comment: simple **dictionary comprehension** with if condition should do the magic. [Link](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/dictionary-comprehension) here.

Comment: @vaira  Two things: The key *could* be at the end, no prob with that and also the dictionary is not ordered

Comment: Using reduce to loop once and then set d1 for small and d2 for greater keys.
    let dd={517.1: 'h', 182.8:'o', 306.5:'l', 378.2:'a'}

    let dividingKey = '378.2';

    let [ d1, d2 ] =  Object.keys(dd).reduce((arr, key) => {
        if (+key < +dividingKey) {
            arr[0][key] = dd[key];
        } else if((+key > +dividingKey))  {
            arr[1][key] = dd[key];
        }
        return arr;
    }, [{},{}])

    console.log(d1,d2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do something like

```py
key = 378.2
dd = {517.1: 'h', 182.8:'o', 306.5:'l', 378.2:'a'}
d1 = {k:dd[k] for k in dd if k < key}
d2 = {k:dd[k] for k in dd if k > key}
```

Comment: Thank you ! This worked wonders and solved my problem. I also applied even more complicated conditions after the `if` with no problem